# How to have log.info in static method

Tags: java, logging, static

My function looks like:

```
public static double isOverturn(final String reference, final String hypothesis, FieldType fieldType) {
        double overturnScore = 1.0;
        if (StringUtils.isEmpty(reference) || StringUtils.isEmpty(hypothesis))
            return overturnScore;
        Method comparisonMethod = null;
        try {
            comparisonMethod = comparison(fieldType.getName());
            overturnScore = (double) comparisonMethod.invoke(null, reference, hypothesis);
        } catch (NoSuchMethodException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (InvocationTargetException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return overturnScore;
    }
```

I want to have log.info in place of e.printStackTrace. But it is giving me error. How to use log.info in static method?

Comment: Declare your `log` as `static`? (Or pass it in as a parameter)

Comment: Hello, can you show how you created your logger field `log`?  You should have been created it as a static field if you need to log anything in static methods.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Just make your log field static. This is industry standard anyway.
2. That is deplorable error handling. If something goes wrong with your reflective invocation, this method returns 1.0. That seems like very silly behaviour. Generally you should just throw exceptions on if there's nothing you can do to handle it properly (and 'log it and return some throwaway default value' is rarely a valid 'handling it' strategy!), because what you do results in a long chain of exceptions, or code that straight up does the wrong thing, because as they say, garbage in, garbage out, and returning 1.0 in the face of problems with definitions sure sounds like that 1.0 is just garbage, no?
3. You can just catch Exception if your intent is to completely ignore what it all means, shunt it off to a log, and return a default value.